# Proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} ( 1+\frac{1}{a_n}) ^ {a_n} = e$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have to prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{a_n} \right) ^{a_n } = e$ if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$. Does anyone know how to do this without relying on the fact that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right) ^ x = e$. Since my teacher used the first limit to prove the second, I need a proof that relies on the properties of sequences and not real-variable functions. I apologize for my bad English. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: The first statement is equivalent to the second by the sequential definition of continuity so you'll find it hard to do so.

Comment: How do you define $e$ in your case?

Comment: We have defined it as the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$, where $n$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e$ is often *defined* as $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)^k$ for integer $k$ and we can use that definition, which is *not* the same as for *real* $x$*.

Then using $$k\le a_n\le k+1,$$ by monotonicity

$$\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)^k\le \left(1+\dfrac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}\le\left(1+\dfrac1{k+1}\right)^{k+1}.$$

This squeezes to $e$.

---

*The integer version allows us to use the binomial development

$$\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)^k=1+\frac kk+\frac{k(k-1)}{2k^2}+\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!k^3}+\cdots\frac1{k^k}$$

such that the individual terms tend to $1,1,\dfrac12,\dfrac1{3!},\cdots$ for increasing $k$.

Comment: That monotonicity may not be apparent to a beginner.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: that's right.

Comment: I'd say $$\left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)^k\le\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}\le\left(1+\frac1{k}\right)^{k+1},$$

Comment: @AnginaSeng: I don't know if this is true or not, but it is not helpful for the proof.

Comment: Well, it is true, it is easy to prove, and it is helpful as both outer terms tend to $e$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: how do you relate it to $k\le a_n\le k+1$ ?

Comment: $$1+\frac1{k+1}\le1+\frac1{ a_n}\le1+\frac1k$$ etc.

Comment: Actually this is used by RRL in the linked thread.